# Curve modifier destroying mesh when curve vertices are moved

Tags: bezier-curves

First of all, thank you for the help - This issue has got me stumped. I've searched all over the forum and have seen lots of issues, but none that seemingly match mine.

Summary - Curve modifier works fine when curve is flat along the Z axis, but as soon as I move a vertice in the Z axis, it destroys the mesh.

Blender File - [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nZUdRa7jN5ZY-F0gCy_sPC6EYEWA0OTV/view?usp=sharing)

[image: mesh looks fine with array and curve modifier]

As soon as I move the vertice in the Z axis, it ruins the mesh

[image: Moving curve vertice on Z axis ruins the mesh]

I'm not sure what's causing this. I've;

- Applied transforms on 'road'
- Have *not* applied transforms on the curves - that seems to make things worse
- Have centered the origin to the exact same spot, at world 0,0,0

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how to remove the post, but I've found the answer to my question - I needed to go into the 'item' in edit mode and reduce the mean radius back to 1 after the transforms had been applied in object mode.

[image: Mean radius fix]